# Can I use "progress" in this way?

Tags: meaning, verbs, word-usage

I saw the following sentence:

> Something unknown has blocked the progress of the biggest diameter tunnel.

1. Then, can I replace these words as follows:

   > Seattle has progressed the biggest diameter tunnel.
2. Before I read this material, I thought the word "progress" was used to mean something like "start". But it seems to be wrong, because people can't "start" the "biggest diameter tunnel".

   Am I right in thinking "progress" can work as "start"? If not, what should it be?

Comment: If you are an English language learner rather than a native speaker or serious linguist, you might find our sister-site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) to be a better fit for your questions than the current site, given that our charter here at ELU reads: “English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for **linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.”**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better on ell.se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeking to use *progress* in its verb form rather than as a noun.  However, as a verb, it is almost always intransitive, that is, it takes no object. As indicated in [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/progress?q=progress)

> [no object]
>   move forward or onward in space or time

You can say

> Seattle has *made progress* on the biggest diameter tunnel
>
> or
>
> Seattle has *progressed* with the biggest diameter tunnel

In the first example, *progress* is used as a noun, and *made* is the verb. In the second example, *progressed* is a verb (like *started*) but it does not take a direct object. The phrase *with the biggest diameter tunnel* is a prepositional modifier of *progressed*.

While the second is correct, the first would be more common in US usage.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the process of becoming acceptable as a transitive verb.

Wiktionary already accepts the usage:

> **progress** verb
>
> (3) (transitive) To move (something) forward; to advance, to expedite.